# How to stream the content of a large text file with Java 1.6 or earlier?

Tags: java

I need to read fram a text file on a server and then forward the content to a client, so I went with this approach:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(MY_FILE), THE_FILES_ENCODING));
```

And then stored the text content in a *StringBuffer* and sent that object to the client via a socket connection.

However, this approach was not good since the text file is very large and won't fit i memory. So I will have to **stream** the content instead, **using Java 1.6 or earlier.** How would I go about doing this?

I also need to make the stream **laguage indepentent**, i.e. to stream strings rather than objects.

Any help about the subject is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `FileInputStream` wrapped in a `BufferedInputStream` and move those bytes to `SocketOutputStream` wrapped in a `BufferedOutputStream`. You can't really "stream Strings", but you don't need to. Bytes are understood by everyone, and it's a lot faster too.

Answer (score 0):

You may just slice the whole big content into little packages and send them one by one.

By that you can preserve your `String` approach. Create `Strings` only up to a given `maxlength`. Give them `package numbers` and send them over your socket, one by one.

You may also use a `SocketOutputStream` from `Apache Commons`. Here's the Doc: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/io/SocketOutputStream.html